# loading Tabbar controller from view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working with a project in which I have to have a login page and after successful login we should have a tabbar view (I am using tab bar controller) when I try to load the tab bar controller using the following code.Nothing works out.

```
LoginSuccess *viewController = [[LoginSuccess alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginSuccess" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:viewController.tabBarController.view];
        [viewController release];
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do same work but me call appdelegate after success of login response 
`[mAppDelegate loadTabbar];`//call function in delegate file to load tabbar view whom code is follow

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Load TabBar
-(void)loadTabBar
{
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    MyAlarmVC *myAlarmVC = [[MyAlarmVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyAlarmVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myAlarmNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myAlarmVC];
    myAlarmNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myAlarmVC release];


    MyVideosVC *myVideoVC = [[MyVideosVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyVideosVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myVideoNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVideoVC];
    myVideoNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myVideoVC release];


    MyFriendsVC *myFriendVC = [[MyFriendsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFriendsVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myFriendNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFriendVC];
    myFriendNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myFriendVC release];


    MyMessageVC *myMessageVC = [[MyMessageVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMessageVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myMessageNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myMessageVC];
    myMessageNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myMessageVC release];

    MyProfileVC *myProfileVC = [[MyProfileVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyProfileVC" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *myProfileNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myProfileVC];
    myProfileNVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [myProfileVC release];

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myAlarmNVC,myVideoNVC, myFriendNVC,myMessageNVC,myProfileNVC, nil];
    [myAlarmNVC release];
    [myVideoNVC release];
    [myProfileNVC release];
    [myFriendNVC release];
    [myMessageNVC release];
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view ];
    //tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self.tabBarController release];

}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController1 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSArray *vc= tabBarController1.viewControllers;

    for (int i = 0; i < [vc count]; i++) {

        UINavigationController *nc = [vc objectAtIndex:i];

        if (nc == tabBarController1.selectedViewController) {

            continue;
        }

[nc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }

}
```

if you got problem then just tell me the view names of your tabbar

Comment: This is what my appdelegate.h file has                             UIWindow *window;
 UIViewController *rootViewController;
 UITabBarController *loginTabbarController; Could you please explain why you are using navigation cpntroller. In my application I dont need a naviagtion controller. The views names I want to have in tabbar controller are Map,calender and record.

Comment: can you tell me the follow of your project so i can tell the proper code;

Comment: in above code me go to login screen and when me enter login button then call webservice it return response in success of false; if i go success then function loadtabbar is call which is declare in appdelegate

Comment: If you not want to add navigation controller then remove navigation controller lines just put view's object name tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myAlarmVC,myVideoVC, myFriendVC,myMessageVC,myProfileVC, nil];

Comment: This is the function I added to appdelegate.m

Comment: -(void) loadTabbar{

 self.loginTabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
 loginTabbarController.delegate = self;
 loginTabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: Yard_Map, Calender, Summary, nil];
 [self.window addSubview:loginTabbarController.view ];
}

Comment: I get the following warning for [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; loginTabbarController.delegate = self; CLass does not implement UITabbarControllerDelegate protocol and a error for the next line saying expectedexpression before yard_map

Comment: loginTabbarcontroller is what I declared in appdelegate.h as UITabbarController. Can you let me about the function void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController1 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

Comment: I could fix the error I said but not the warning. Could you help me with that.

Comment: not take care of that warning me also got warning that not make any effect on ur program